# How to deserialize enum and array in .NET 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, jqgrid, json-deserialization

jqgrid filter deserialization in ASP.NET 5 MVC application fails using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer

To reproduce, run the code

```
var _filters ="{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"Toode\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"\"}]}";

var filtersList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Filter>(_filters, new JsonSerializerOptions
                { 
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
                });
```

Result:

```
The JSON value could not be converted to MyApp.Controllers.GroupOp. Path: $.groupOp | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 16.


System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to MyApp.Controllers.GroupOp. Path: $.groupOp | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 16.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException(String message)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.EnumConverter`1.Read(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.ReadJsonAndSetMember(Object obj, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
```

jqgrid classes used in deserialization:

```
public class Filter
{
    public GroupOp GroupOp { get; set; }
    public List<Rule> Rules { get; set; }
    public List<Filter> Groups { get; set; }
}

public enum GroupOp
{
    AND,
    OR
}

public class Rule
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public Operations Op { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public enum Operations
{
    eq,
    ne,
    cn,
    le
}
```

In .NET 4.6 it worked using

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var filtersList = serializer.Deserialize<Filter>(_filters);
```

How to make it work in .NET 5 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Net 5 you have to install Newtonsoft.Json using Nuget. This code allows to deserilize

```
var _filters = "{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"Toode\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"\"}]}";
    var filtersList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Filter>(_filters);
    
}


public class Filter
{
    public GroupOp groupOp { get; set; }
    public List<Rule> rules { get; set; }
    
}
```

Comment: How to deserialize with .NET 5 builtin `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` . Application uses it in all other places. No reason to use two serializers in application.

Comment: Since the application is being converted to Net 5 IMHO it makes sense to use a newest serializer too. In this case you just have to change one word in your code. If you try to use the old serializer you will have to change your code much more significantly.

Comment: What word should changed to use  newest, `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`.  jqgrid classes holding properties can changed also if this is required

Comment: It looks like enum values  AND , OR and eq, ne, cn, le cannot created from strings. Maybe custom convert can specified which convertes json strings to enums

Comment: @Andrus It deserialize your string correctly. You asked just for deserialization. When it serialize the created object again, it uses values instead of string. And it is correct. If you deserialize it again you will have enum strings again, as in the beginning.